# How can I change add to cart button on category page to saw view more and route to product page?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

Instead of adding an item to the cart from the category page I would like to instead have it simply route to the product page.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` either in your custom module or custom theme to replace Add to cart button with a product page link.

Following is the sample code to override it using the custom module.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Anshu_Custom::product/list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                        $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <a class="product-item-link"
                                       href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View Details') ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= ($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_product->getSku() ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the sample code, you can modify according to you requirement.

Comment: I know its possible. I was looking for code examples.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan Sorry, Didn't get your point "code examples".

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan I have edited my answer with the code sample.